# Evento Onclik do chosen-select

Tags: javascript, html

Boa Tarde

Pessoal estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando chosen-select no lugar do select convencional e me surgiu uma necessidade sobre o evento onclick desse select abaixo fiz a seguinte declaração:

```js
function teste() {
         alert('teste1');
       }
       
 $("#select").bind("click", function () {
        alert($(this).val());
       });
```

```html
<select id="select" data-placeholder="Informe o Usuário..." onkeyup="teste();" class="chosen-select" tabindex="2">
            <option onclick="teste();" value="00">Nenhum</option>
            <option onclick="teste();" value="01">Eder</option>
            <option onclick="teste();" value="02">Fabiano</option>
            <option onclick="teste();" value="03">Eduardo</option>    
    </select>
```

A função **teste()** não é executada de forma alguma porém à segunda rotina é capturada alguém sabe me explicar porque não funciona a função?

Answer (score 0):

A tag `option` não suporta o evento `onclick`.

Se você quiser ter acesso ao `value` da `option` pode usar o evento `onchange` na tag `select`:

```js
function teste(value){
  alert(value);
}
```

```html
<select id="select" data-placeholder="Informe o Usuário..." onchange="teste(value);" class="chosen-select" tabindex="2">
  <option value="00">Nenhum</option>
  <option value="01">Eder</option>
  <option value="02">Fabiano</option>
  <option value="03">Eduardo</option>    
</select>
```